# Breadboard circuit not working as intended

Tags: voltage

I'm doing a segment of my complete circuit for my school project. But somehow it doesn't seem to work , I've double checked the connections multiple times and I can't seem to find an error.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl1IWj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the actual connection

[image: Actual Connection]

With reference to the schematic , the inputs A3 ~ A0 represent a 4 bit number that is set from my 4 BIT DIP switch in the actual connection , the input B0 serves as a control bit, and the rectangle labelled "VCC" is the VCC channel on my breadboard(Denoted by the red wires ) , all VCC connections are done with red wire , grounds with brown wire and interconnections with grey wires. AND1 represents the MSB of the output 4 bit number and AND4 represents the LSB. The circuit is supposed to work like this :

When B0 is on , the circuit will output the same 4 bit number as the input , when B0 is off , the circuit will output all 0's.

My circuit is for some odd reason not working as intended , I'm using an 74LS08P QUAD 2 Input AND chip.

Thanks :D

Comment: Are those resistors on the bottom right corner of the breadboard acting as pull-downs? I don't see any resistors in your schematic.

Comment: What @DanLaks said.  You'll need pulldown resistors on the input lines.  If they're left floating (when the switches are open), the result is indeterminate.

Comment: Take a close look at the `B0` switch wiring (the upper switch of the 2-gang unit). It doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: Doctor, doctor there's something wrong with me but I'm not going to tell you the symptoms (or what species of animal I am) you have to guess. What do you expect the circuit (as drawn) to do?

Comment: Is there power?  Rip it up and start again.  Add one piece at a time, checking as you go.

Comment: I don't see any bypass capacitor. Needs a small ceramic 0.1uF capacitor across the power pins, as close as possible to each IC. Especially when using solderless breadboard, where there are significant parasitic inductance.

Comment: Hi , thanks for all the replies. 

@DanLaks Yes the resistors are acting as pull downs for the DIP switch , I forgot to include them in the schematic , they are all 12k Ohm resistors. 

-DaveTweed:The B0 switch wiring is actually going across to the other channel , you can't see it as the 2 bit DIP switch is blocking it.

-Andyaka: I've already stated how I expect the circuit to behave in the post itself.

Comment: Can you please update your schematic to show how every component (resistor, power supply, caps, etc) are connected to the circuit? Inevitably the problem has something to do with what you're not showing in the schematic. The photo you included is inconclusive.

Comment: Done. I've used a voltmeter to test my voltage regulator circuit ( circuit on the bottom left of the image ) and it works. The problem is with the DIP switches and the AND gates. The DIP switches work fine on their own , but somehow the AND gate IC is not giving the correct output.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're seeing? Describe the symptoms (by editing the question).

Comment: Along the right-hand side of both DIP switches is a gray wire that appears to end one row below the pins of the switches. From the photo, it doesn't look like those connect to anything. What do they connect to?

Comment: You just need to troubleshoot this circuit, a good skill to learn and keep learning.  Do you have a voltmeter?  you should be able to test every node in the circuit.  First check that the power supply is getting to each place it should.  If you have a current meter inline or in the power supply then make sure the current is reasonable (no power/ground shorts).  Then check the input side.  Are the switches and pulldowns controlling the input pins of the IC correctly?  If so, then check one AND gate at a time for each combination of its inputs.  You'll find the problem by being systematic.

Comment: Related to the missing bypass capacitors: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/17128/35022

Answer (score 1):

The inputs of bipolar TTL parts, such as your 74LS08, source current, so need a very low value pull-down resistor to ensure the input is seen as a low.  You don't show the resistors on the schematic, so I'm not sure of their value.

Traditionally, we put the switch between the input pin and ground, with a 5K1 or so pull-up resistor to +5V.  The switch to ground will definitely be seen as a Low.  Unfortunately, this reverses the logic on the switches, so a switch on is a Low, and switch off is High.

Comment: For my case , the switch is connected between the +5V and the input pins of my IC's , the ground and pull down resistor are on the input pin side of the switch. Thus , the input will be pulled down to ground when the switch is open , and will be pulled up to high when the switch is closed. So I don't think follows active low logic like in your description ?

Comment: As @Peter Bennet said, you need a low pull-down. The [first] 74LS08 datasheet [I found] says -0.4mA max current when Vin is 0.4V and a max of 0.8V as logic low, which implies a 1k to 2k  pull down, so 12k is much too high.